# Why is an abelian variety not a finite flat group scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is it exactly that stops an abelian variety from being a finite flat group scheme?

Comment: It's not finite, unless it's zero-dimensional. More precisely, if $G$ is a finite flat group scheme over a field $k$, then $G_{\overline{k}}$ is a zero-dimensional variety over $\overline{k}$. In particular,  $G(\overline{k})$ is finite. However, if $A$ is a positive-dimensional abelian variety $A$ over $k$, then $A(\overline{k})$ is infinite.

Comment: My confusion was based on the definition saying that for a group scheme $G$ over a noetherian scheme $S$ to be finite then $O_{G}$ had to be of finite rank over $O_{S}$. I thought that this referred to $O_{G}(G)$ rather than the sheaf of rings $O_{G}$ but my uncle has now cleared this up for me. Thanks for your help.